# how to send messages using only IP address within LAN

Tags: java, android, ip-address

I have two wifi modules that connects to my access point. my android phone connects to the same access point. Is there a way in Java to be able to send a message to any of the clients from my phone using just the IP address. I do not want to run a server on my phone.

I'll appreciate any assistance. Thanks

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here to tell what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: What im trying to do is to send a message from my phone to a wifi module without having the server to client connection. both my phone and the wifi module are connected to my access point. I can see their both device's IP address. My question was to know if there is a way to send message using this IP address from phone to module.

Comment: I have to second @Falmarri at the moment it is difficult to help you because it is unclear what you want to achieve. Maybe the following questions help a bit: What do you mean by 'message'? A text message? Is there a specific protocol you would like to use? What kind of application do you want to implement?

Comment: I want a send bytes from the phone to the module. I'm trying not to use a server-client application. The idea is to connect the module to my hotspot on the phone, and now send bytes to the module using the IP i get from the hotspot. Does that make it more understandable?? I dont know how to put it into better words

Comment: One way to do that will be to launch a service on your android device, use socket programming and listen on a particular port.

Comment: hey Siddharth. I'm trying to avoid making a server application on the phone. Is there any other way to directly be able to send a message to client if I have its IP address??

Answer (score 0):

I feel there is a confusion about IP addresses and servers in general. An IP address is a way to find an entity on the network (it is an address). Since your phone is connected to the same access point, it is (very likely) on the same subnet. What that means is that it can talk to any of the other entities without going through a gateway, that is all.

While it is able to talk to them, there has still to be some entity listening. When your phone sends a message to a particular address (the other node on the network), the packet may make it there, but for the communication to proceed:

- There has to be some listener on the other end that picks that incoming message
- The communication has to follow a prescribed set of rules (protocol)

From what I gather, your phone is acting as the client, not the server. It initiates communication with the other entity on the network. Depending on which node on the network you are trying to talk to, that node is supposed to be expecting that communication and know how to carry it forward.

If you clarify the setup and your desire, may be you can get more to the point response.

Comment: dude i couldn't have put this in better words myself. Subnets and gateway are key words here. Both phone and module are on the same subnet.

Comment: and you're right My phone acts as a client too. well my supervisor says avoid using server-client communication because at first I had a SocketServer on the phone and the module joins to my home router and looks for my server on the phone and connects to it. But now i cant use a server so I was thinking why not create a hotspot on the phone as the hotspot acts like a server right? and I get an IP address of the client from the hotspot and try to send bytes to the module. I don't exactly know how to do so. Does this make any sense?

Comment: What is still not clear is who on the "module" you are trying to talk to. In a phone service analogy, you know the number to dial, but is there someone to pick up. Otherwise you can dial, and you will get an "unanswered" response.

Comment: the module here is a wifi module from Roving Networks. its not a PC but its a Wireless LAN module.

Answer (score -1):

What you were not understanding here is that you can send the message to that device with ip address but that data will not be shown on that device's screen because you didn't provided any port number for a process which is listening on that particular device. Your message will be sent but the device would not know what do with it.